# Why won't my bash script read numbers from the command line?

Tags: macos, bash

I am using MacOS to run this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

BADARGS=65
if [ -z $1 ]
then
    echo "Usage:`basename $0` first-number second-number..."
    exit $BADARGS
fi

for number in $@
do
    echo $number
done | sort -n

#END
```

The script should print the numbers entered on the command line in increasing order, but the script is not reading in the numbers. How do I fix that?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question.  Did you run it? What happened? What did you expect?

Comment: I compiled it and I ran it, but it is not reading any numbers from the command line.

Comment: How did you compile a `bash` script?

Comment: Well I gave it execute permissions. chmod +x filename.

Comment: Do you want your script to read values from stdin, or are you expecting the values on the command line as arguments? I'm confused about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are asking for this:

```
/path/to/myscript.sh 5 3 89 12
```

where /path/to/  is the location (directory path) of your script.  If it is in the current working directory:

```
./myscript.sh 5 3 89 12
```

Comment: YES! Thank you :) I was doing it backwards

Comment: Backwards?  What do you mean by that?

Comment: I second that question....

Comment: probably `5 3 89 12 ./myscript.sh` :-)

Comment: @umlaeute is correct.